# How do I control how many task instances are working at any given time with Asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've made two queue system with Asyncio.

`Responder` takes a list of links, asks each one for a response, and puts the result in a queue. `Parser` takes the response from the queue, parses it, and adds it to another queue. `Submitter` grabs the parsed object from the queue, and submits it to the database.

The code below shows how I'm creating the tasks. For `Submitter` and `Parser` I create 100 instances. The issue seems to be, that once `Submitter` gets to 100 instances, that's it - the submit queue just starts to back up. It basically stops doing its job. Nothing gets submitted anymore. `Responder` and `Parser` will usually carry on.

Once a `submitter` has done it's job, how do I recycle it? I don't want to necessarily create a `responder` for every single link in my list. It's the part at the end of my code which I don't fully understand - `for s in submitters:
s.cancel()`
This kills my instances *after* everything is done, or *after* the instance has done its job?

```
async def bulk_submit(not_submitted: set, **kwargs):
    parse_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    submit_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"}

    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60*60)
    async with ClientSession(headers=headers, timeout=timeout) as session:
        tasks=[]
        i=0
        for link in not_submitted:
            i+=1
            tasks.append(
                responder(f'RESPONDER-{i}',url=link, session=session, parse_queue=parse_queue, **kwargs)
            )

        parsers = [asyncio.create_task(parser(f'PARSER-{n}', parse_queue=parse_queue, submit_queue=submit_queue)) for n in range (100)]
        submitters = [asyncio.create_task(submitter(f'SUBMITTER-{n}', submit_queue=submit_queue,)) for n in range (100)]


        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await parse_queue.join()
        await episode_queue.join()
        await submit_queue.join()
        for s in submitters:
            s.cancel()
        for p in parsers:
            p.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue seems to be, that once `Submitter` gets to 100 instances, that's it - the submit queue just starts to back up. [...]
>
> Once a `submitter` has done it's job, how do I recycle it?

You haven't shown us the code of `submitter`, so it's hard to tell how to solve the problem, or even what problem you are solving precisely. Based on the code you did show, one could guess that the submitter simply returns after processing a single queue item. You are effectively creating 100 submitters running in parallel, but access to the queue serializes them. When each of those does its job, there is no one else to drain the submit queue and the work stops.

To fix this, you don't need to recycle the submitter, you just need to change it to keep dequeueing queue items instead of exiting after getting one. It should look like this:

```
async def submitter(name, submit_queue):
    while True:
        item = await submit_queue.get()
        ... process the item ...
```

With this setup you don't need to create 100 submitters to run in parallel, one will suffice. (Unless you actually *want* some degree of parallelism, that is, in which case you can create as many of them as you want submits happening in parallel.)

> It's the part at the end of my code which I don't fully understand - `for s in submitters: s.cancel()` This kills my instances after everything is done, or after the instance has done its job?

I suspect that in your code the cancellation is a no-op because all your `submitter` coroutines have *completed* by the time you call `cancel()` (cancelling a completed task is ignored).

Normally the idea is to kill off the idle workers after their work is done and they are no longer needed. For example, if `submitter` contains an infinite loop as shown above, cancellation will [prevent it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576263/1600898) from waiting forever for new queue item (and never receiving them) after `bulk_submit` returns.